# Play each tweenLite after click

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, gsap

I have 4 tweeens using tweenLite, what I want is for the first to play then when the user click the mouse the seconds, then click the mouse again the third then fourth.

these are my tweens:

```
TweenLite.to(page1ani1,1,{y:135});
TweenLite.to(page1ani2, 1, {x:39});
TweenLite.to(page1ani3, 1, {y:390});
TweenLite.to(page1ani4, 1, {y:460});
```

I have tryed on stage click like this:

```
numPressed = 0;
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, numberseq, false, 0, true);
function numberseq(e:MouseEvent):void {
        numPressed++;
}

TweenLite.to(page1ani1,1,{y:135});

if(numPressed == 1) {
    TweenLite.to(page1ani2, 1, {x:39});
}
if(numPressed == 2) {
    TweenLite.to(page1ani3, 1, {y:390});
}
if(numPressed == 3) {
    TweenLite.to(page1ani4, 1, {y:460});
}
```

but to no avail.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Ian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify your `numberseq()` like so,

```
function numberseq(e:MouseEvent):void {
    numPressed++;

      if(numPressed == 1) {
          TweenLite.to(page1ani2, 1, {x:39});
      }else
      if(numPressed == 2) {
        TweenLite.to(page1ani3, 1, {y:390});
      }else
      if(numPressed == 3) {
         TweenLite.to(page1ani4, 1, {y:460});
      }
 }
```

Comment: Yeah, this works to originally bring each tween in, but If i move back a frame then forward to this frame it doesnt work, nothing appears when you click.

Comment: Are you updating `numPressed` accordingly?

Comment: Yeah think that solved it, on every page i reset 0 and removed he numberseq. Thankyou

Comment: Not sure it is working now, how do I update numPressed? Just like : numPressed = 0;?

Comment: If you want Previous and Next page behavior then for prev make numPressed-- and for Next action set numPressed++. You will need two separate events to check if action is Prev or Next.

Comment: navLeft.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, goLeft);
function goRight(e:MouseEvent):void {
 numPressed--;
 gotoAndStop(6); 
}

Comment: Can you explain what exactly is page1ani2, page1ani3?